# Reading_xml_file_using C#

Tags: c#, xml

What's the best way to read a xml file using C#. My xml file looks like this:

```
<modules>
    <module file="file1" version="2.0"/>
    <module file="file2" version="2.0"/>
</modules>
```

I just want to get module's filename and version and store it to a list.

Answer (score 0):

Mos preferred choice, `LINQ to XML`. It's so much simpler and easier.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filepath);

var results = doc.Root
   .Elements("module")
   .Select(x=>new 
    { 
        file = (string)x.Attribute("file") , 
        version = (string)x.Attribute("version") 
    });
```